# Kotlin || Recycleview item is not inflating: Unreachable code on each overridden method of RecycleView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am creating the Custom `Recycleview`  in `Kotlin`
I am not getting any exception in the code and it run perfectly but the concern is that item is not getting appear on the `Recycleview` beacuase the code is unreachable in Adapter class.

> **Waring :-** Unreachable code on the overridden method of `RecycleView` adapter.

[image: Captured image]

Please check my Adapter and Activity class

**Adapter Class**

```
class CustomRecycleAdapter(val data: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.recycle_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        return data.size;
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        val item = data[position]
        println("Data is here==>>> "+item)
        holder?.textViewName?.text = item;
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


        val textViewName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)

    }
}
```

**Activity class**

```
class FirstRecycleViewExample : AppCompatActivity() {
    val data = arrayListOf<String>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.first_recycleview)

        val recycler_view =   findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)

        data.add("First Data")
        data.add("Second Data")
        data.add("Third Data")
        data.add("Forth Data")
        data.add("Fifth Data")

        //creating our adapter
        val adapter = CustomRecycleAdapter(data)

        //now adding the adapter to recyclerview
        recycler_view.adapter = adapter

    }


}
```

Comment: Remove the TODO("not implemented") and see if it works

Comment: @AlfMoh , Unreachable error removed..But yet again data is NOT infalted in the list

Comment: pass context in the constructor and use that context in Layout.from().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added a layout manager for the RecyclerView.Just add a `LinearLayoutManager` OR a `GridLayoutManager`

`recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)`

Comment: Thanks Joel..What a silly mistake, i have done :( ...In android i have used it many times..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

your code will not run based on you using the TODO function

check kotlin site for more details [TODO function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-t-o-d-o.html)

this will always throw an exception unless you remove it or comment it out like so

[comment out TODO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r5wz.png)

To validate answer check your log messages and cross reference the error message against the message set within your TODO

If this is not the issues then its most likely that you haven't set up your recycle_view.layoutManager to be a LinearLayoutManager, GridLayoutManager etc.

this would be done within the class that you have set the content layout to when showing your recycle view on the main UI e.g.         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your input..+1 for the input :)